# Share Google Calendar with all events to another user - PHP API

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

Can I share one public calendar with another user using Google Calendar API? so when I update the calendar everyone gets the update too, without enter to my website again.

I saw that I can create a calendar and add events, but what I want is to share my calendar not create a new one in another user account.

Thanks :)

Comment: Try the [Google Calendar Access Control List](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/acl), use `Acl: insert` to create an access control rule for a user. Hope this helps.

Comment: I found it today, here is the code, thanks pal



$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
    $calendarListEntry = new Google_Service_Calendar_CalendarListEntry();
    $calendarListEntry->setId($calendarId);
    $createdCalendarListEntry = $service->calendarList->insert($calendarListEntry);
    echo $createdCalendarListEntry->getSummary();